# How to stop agGrid from truncating whitespaces between the values and show the text as is?

Tags: css, ag-grid

agGrid truncates multiple spaces in between. What if the user does not want to trim the spaces and show the text as is.

[image: Have a look at this screenshot here]

Comment: I think this official link is useful for your case: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-height/

Answer (score 2):

agGrid does not trim the [white spaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) between your value. It just removes the spaces when displaying. If you want to preserve all of the white spaces in the original value, try adding this line in your css file.

```css
.ag-cell {
  white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64375360/how-to-stop-aggrid-from-truncating-whitespaces-between-the-values-and-show-the-t]